# Zend Framework 2 - filters

Tags: zend-framework2

New to ZF2 and trying to understand some of its nuances.

I have a couple of questions:

**Question 1**

I'm using configuration to set out the input filters for a form field (example below).  When you have a filter and a validator on the same element like this does the filtered data get passed to the validator? So in the example below if I entered "   Hello world      " with a load of white space would that white space be stripped from the string before the validator evaluates it?

```
'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Zend\Validator\StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'min' => 3,
                        'max' => 11
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

**Question 2**

I've seen examples where people have set a filter using just a name e.g. 'strtolower' as per the below code.  What I can't figure out is whether this alias is set somewhere like with validators in ValidatorPluginManager.  Where are the aliases set for filters?

```
    'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'strtolower'),
            ),
            'validators' => array( /*validator stuff*/),
        ),
```

Really appreciate any advice as I've been crunching the docks but can't find answers to these questions.

Drongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

Yes, when using input filters the value will first be filtered before validation takes place.

**Question2**

Have a look at the [`FilterPluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-filter/blob/master/src/FilterPluginManager.php#L30) for all the aliases you can use for the "stock" filters.

Check [`ValidatorPluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/ValidatorPluginManager.php#L25) for an overview of the validators.

Comment: Thanks mate that was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@BramGerritsen is very right in his answer so I upvoted his, but here is some additional information to his answer for your **Question 1**:

There are special cases where validation happens **before** filtering. An example is [the `FileInput` class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html). With file upload the files should be validated before we do anything else so that any validation will be done prior to any filters that may rename/move/modify the file... (check the link).
I could imagine other people having custom input classes where they do the same (I actually have some classes like that myself).